# React image is not loading conditionally

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In line 7 where I am using `postPage`, my image is not displaying.

```
    function Post(id ,post, postPage) {
      return (
        <div className='p-3 cursor-pointer border-b border-gray-700'>
            {postPage && (<img src={post?.userImg} alt="" className='h-10 w-10 rounded-full mr-4'/>)} 
            <div className='flex flex-col space-y-2 w-full'>
                <div className={`flex ${!postPage && "justify-between"}`}>
                    {postPage && (
                        <img src={post?.userImg} alt="" className='h-10 w-10 rounded-full mr-4'/>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default Post
```

This is the code from another file that I am using, and I am not able to figure out if this is the problem.

```js
           const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "posts"), {
              id: session.user.uid,
              username: session.user.name,
              userImg: session.user.image,
              tag: session.user.tag,
              text: input,
              timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
            });
        
            const imageRef = ref(storage, `posts/${docRef.id}/image`);
```

Comment: What are the values of `post` and `postPage` when you're seeing this issue? Can you also include the final, generated HTML markup for one of your posts that's not working?